# standard deviation presto

Tags: sql, presto

I would like to calculate the standard deviation for `avg_total_orders_last_30_days using the avg_total_orders_last_12_months`.

**sample table**

```
customer_id | avg_total_orders_last_30_days | avg_total_orders_last_12_months

939           103                             94
441           107                             118
082           313                             293
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```
select 
    customer_id
    avg_total_orders_last_30_days,
    avg_total_orders_last_12_months,
    approx_distinct(SUM(avg_total_orders_last_12_months)) OVER (partition by customer_id ) as stdev_rep
from table
group by 1
```

Comment: Currently I don't fully understand your data structure. Is it possible for same `customer_id` to have different rows with different `avg_total_orders_last_30_days`?

Comment: no this table is on a customer level and each customer only has one value for avg_total_orders_last_30_days and avg_total_orders_last_12_months

Comment: Then why do you have any grouping applied?

Comment: Also can you please explain what standard deviation for avg_total_orders_last_30_days _using the avg_total_orders_last_12_months_ means, i.e. please give some examples of input and output and formula to get the output, if it is not obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're trying to do, but your [avg_total_orders_last_12_months] field contains numbers that are too large to act as 'e' for approx_distinct.

[Approx Distinct Link](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html?highlight=approx_distinct)

*approx_distinct(x, e) → bigint#*

*Returns the approximate number of distinct input values. This function provides an approximation of count(DISTINCT x). Zero is returned if all input values are null.
This function should produce a standard error of no more than e, which is the standard deviation of the (approximately normal) error distribution over all possible sets. It does not guarantee an upper bound on the error for any specific input set. **The current implementation of this function requires that e be in the range of [0.0040625, 0.26000]**.*

If you're looking to get the true sample standard deviation for the field use the STDDEV(x) as outlined below:

[Standard Deviation Link](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html#stddev)